# Server keep restarting after reaching 'starting web server'

Tags: centos, ntpd, signals, apcupsd

Recently one of our server failed and wont start services. I looked over the `/var/log/messages` and found this:

```
Dec 27 00:53:48 localhost apcupsd[3413]: apcupsd FATAL ERROR in linux-usb.c at line 609 Cannot find UPS device -- For a link to detailed USB trouble shooting information, please see <http://www.apcupsd.com/suppo$
Dec 27 00:53:48 localhost apcupsd[3413]: apcupsd error shutdown completed
Dec 27 00:53:59 localhost kernel: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
Dec 27 00:53:59 localhost kernel: bttv: driver version 0.9.16 loaded
Dec 27 00:53:59 localhost kernel: bttv: using 8 buffers with 2080k (520 pages) each for capture
Dec 27 00:56:13 localhost ntpd[3397]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
Dec 27 00:56:13 localhost rpc.statd[3255]: Caught signal 15, un-registering and exiting.
Dec 27 00:56:14 localhost kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Dec 27 00:56:14 localhost kernel: Kernel log daemon terminating.
Dec 27 00:56:15 localhost exiting on signal 15
```

First, I checked logs on other servers,and found that first two errors about apcpusd is present there also, but there are no errors after that. Server is `CentOS 5.11` running `Netavis Observer 4.3`